# Why Monad's bind() method must return a func which then return a Monad?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

Could anyone please tell me the difference between `map/fmap` (defined by Functor) and `flatMap/bind/lift` (defined by Monads) in https://gist.github.com/babygau/b80861ff5eabc582f7fa#file-monad-js? The former takes a function and return a Monad, the latter takes a function and return a function which then also returns a Monad. The question is why the latter need take extra step to return a Monad???

```
// Monads apply a function that returns a wrapped values to a wrapped value
// and then return a wrapped value
// Monads are chainable
class Wrapper {
  constructor(val) {
    console.log('Created a wrapped value ' + val);
    this.val = val;
  }
  // Functor's `fmap` in Haskell
  map(func) {
    return new Wrapper(func(this.val));
  }
  // Monad's `>>=` (pronounced bind) in Haskell
  flatMap(func) {
    return func(this.val);
  }
  // Monad's `return` in Haskell
  static of(val) {
    return new Wrapper(val);
  }
}

// Monad
console.log(Wrapper.of([1,2,3]).flatMap(function(val) {val.push(4);return Wrapper.of(val);})); //=> [1, 2, 3, 4]

// Functor
console.log(Wrapper.of([1,2,3]).map(function(val) {val.push(4); return val;})); //=> [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Please write the relevant code **IN** the question. SO even lets you write executable snippets.

Comment: @DenysSéguret I edited the post for your request!

Comment: Btw, we call it [`chain` in JavaScript](https://github.com/fantasyland/fantasy-land#chain)

Comment: `flatMap` does not return a function. It *takes* a function.

Comment: Your return values are not correct. It's `Wrapper { val: [1, 2, 3, 4] }` actually

Comment: @Bergi youre right. I just want to mention the 2 methods return the same output!

Comment: @babygau: But with different arguments (callback functions)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example:

```
// Monad
console.log(Wrapper.of([1,2,3]).flatMap(function(val) {val.push(4);return Wrapper.of(val);})); //=> [1, 2, 3, 4]

// Functor
console.log(Wrapper.of([1,2,3]).map(function(val) {val.push(4); return val;})); //=> [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Is overly simplified. If you have a function of type `a -> b`, like you do (`.push(4) :: Array -> Array`), it's trivial to convert it to `a -> m b` (this is `return`), or relatively easy to lift it directly to `m a -> m b` like your `map` does.

However, we're looking at a case where your `Wrapper` is an Identity Monad. Consider real `Maybe`:

```
divBy2 :: Int -> Maybe Int
divBy2 a = if a `mod` 2 == 0 then Just a `div` 2 else Nothing
```

This function expresses a computation in `Maybe` very clearly. If you have `>>=`, you can chain it easily:

```
pure 8 >>= divBy2 >>= divBy2
```

However, if you only have `fmap`, there's no way of chaining such a function! (Without using something like `join`, which is defined in terms of `>>=` anyway).

Specifically, if you have a value `5 :: Int` and a function `Int -> Maybe Int`, you can feed it in that function. But once you've done that, and have a value of `Maybe Int`, you'd need to *extract* the value out of the `Maybe`, and only then feed it to the next function. This is **exactly** what `>>=` is doing.

Functions returning actual monadic computations are very powerful, and that's where they have advantage over Functors.

Comment: Thank you, after reading a Haskell book, I find your answer is the most relevant!

Answer (score 3):

`fmap/map`, usually defined like `(a -> b) -> f a -> f b` in Haskell, and usually more like `f a -> (a -> b) -> f b` in js, expect the provided function to transform *only the value* in the monad, and the result monad is created by `fmap`.

`bind/flatMap/chain`, has a signature of `f a -> (a -> f b) -> f b`, has more freedom --- it can return monadic values beyond what `Monad.of(singleValue)` can express.

As an example, the `List` monad has a `fmap` method to return a `List` of the same length with values transformed by provided function, so that:

```
fmap (1 +) [1, 2, 3] == [2, 3, 4]
```

But what if you want a `List` of different length?  It is not possible with `fmap` because `fmap` always return a `List` of the same length.  `bind` solves that.

```
Prelude> [1..3] >>= \x -> [x..x+2]
[1,2,3,2,3,4,3,4,5]
```

`bind`, or `flatMap`, for `List`s are usually defined as concatenating the resulting `List`s together, so that you can return a `List` to say "I want this element to become zero, or 2, or more elements in the resulting `List`".

Answer (score 1):

Because it can make for elegant and convenient code. For example, you have multiple operations that can return `MyObject` or `null` (in a monad, of course, so perhaps `Option<MyObject>` or so). You can easily chain them together, without actually checking if they returned null or not. If any operation returns null, all the other operations simply won't do anything.

```
//I assume Option is a kind of Wrapper
function canReturnNull(myVal) {
    //something that can return Option(myChangedVal) or Option(null)
}

var result = Option(myObj).flatMap(canReturnNull1).flatMap(canReturnNull2).flatMap(canReturnNull3);
```

If it returned a value instead of a monad, I could not chain the operations together like that.

That is, of course, for the Option monad. I recommend reading about the various kinds of monads in Haskell tutorials.

Comment: But `Functor` is chainable too. If you look into the snippet, I have 2 methods. They all return Monad Type and could be chained.

Comment: Well, in Javascript, those can be used the same way, because it is not statically typed. Also, your monad doesn't really do anything. Certain kinds of monads allow you to do different things. The Option/Maybe monad for example allows you to chain operations that can return null without explicitly checking for it. Monads are a kind of subclass of functors, really.

Comment: Tks @ralh for your answer. I do understand some type of Monad as you pointed out. I am just confused about the Monad `bind()` method in this case because it need extra step to return a Monad. Trying to figure out why that such implementation is needed.

Comment: @babygau: No, it doesn't "need extra step". It **allows** you to have an extra step. When you have a function that returns the monadic type already (for some reason), you cannot use `map` - you need to use `flatMap`. Some data types have this capability, they are monads, others don't - they're only functors.

Comment: @Bergi, thank you. I like your answer. Monads allow me to have an extra tool to manipulate the data.

Answer (score 0):

There are various reasons: sometimes its not even possible to return a value. Take JS promises for example, and lets say `bind` was `then`. If you do an async operation within `then`s callback you cannot return a value - but you can return a promise.

In most languages with static types its not possible  for the callback to then to return both a sync value or a promise. So promises in those languages would have 2 methods: `fmap` only lets you apply sync functions to the promise wrapper, `bind` only async.